# How to make different sections in a single page (explanation inside)

Tags: html, css

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is making a one pager for my website. Basically there is an index page, and, for example, if someone clicks on "Services" it will send them to the services page. This "services" page will display 5 or 6 services, all in one page. So basically when the user clicks on a navigation item, it scrolls using jQuery to the div where the information is displayed.

Now what I don't want is the user to see the section below the one he's / she's actually reading. So for example I have a service called Edition and another Conception. If I'm reading the "Edition" section, I don't want to see the "Conception" just right now, unless I scroll to it. My first thought was using margins, but I mean if I'm on a 1024x768 display the margin would not be the same as a 1920x1080.

So basically, I'm looking for a way to display my content for my services on one page, but each different service is displayed so, unless the visitor scrolls, the next section under it is not seen.

Hope it makes sense, and thanks for any support and help!

Comment: are you trying to make tabbed content in one page?
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ might be your solution.

Let's say you hit the last content block, everything above should be visible? You want it to scroll to the next content, not just show/hide?

Comment: Not really, I want a normal page displayed, but the next content should not be seen if that's not the one we want to see. For example right now if you click on "Edition", it will scroll to the edition content, but under you will see "Conception" and its content aswell. The easy way would be to add, let's say 500px margin-bottom to "Edition", but that will differ with every screen resolution

Comment: Not if you use a fixed height on your content container I believe. If I'm following you correctly, you're scrolling into content from top to bottom, not left to right?

Comment: Here's an image to try and explain what I'm trying to do. http://i.minus.com/iAO29CMcgdMIU.jpg

Comment: have a look at what DuckDuckGo do with automatically loading more results when you scroll to the bottom of the current list. Maybe there is something for you in there.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you'd need to define a navigation bar class, and a class used to store each section of the page.  Setting the height of the section to 100% will ensure that the section takes up the entire height of the user's screen.  Note that this only works when the height for both the html and the body are set to 100% as well.

Set up your nav so the position is fixed on the screen, and use links to call a javascript function that navigates to the correct section based on the id of the link.

html:

```
<nav>
    <a class="nav" id="1" href="#">Section 1</a>
    <a class="nav" id="2" href="#">Section 2</a>
    <a class="nav" id="3" href="#">Section 3</a>
</nav>
<div class="section" id="1">
    Section 1
</div>
<div class="section" id="2">
    Section 2
</div>
<div class="section" id="3">
    Section 3
</div>
```

css:

```
a {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
$('.nav').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#' + id + '.section').offset().top)
    }, 1000);
});
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqcuN/2/

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I don't know about him, but this was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: How to add some spacing between the hyperlinks?

Answer (score 0):

I guess by image you uploaded that this is what you are looking for:

HTML

```
<article>
<h1>Edition</h1>
<div>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}
article {width: 500px; height:100%; margin: 0 auto;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5HLNE/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include paging technique in your HTML page, so for each section you need to provide an id and a hyper link for that.