# different sections in a single page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899333/how-to-make-different-sections-in-a-single-page-explanation-inside) for using different sections in a single page. The demo works fine but when I use these codes it won't work at all. here is the code :

html:

```
<nav>
    <a class="nav" id="1" href="#">Section 1</a>
    <a class="nav" id="2" href="#">Section 2</a>
    <a class="nav" id="3" href="#">Section 3</a>
</nav>
<div class="section" id="1">
    Section 1
</div>
<div class="section" id="2">
    Section 2
</div>
<div class="section" id="3">
    Section 3
</div>
```

css:

```
a {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#' + id + '.section').offset().top)
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

This is exactly what i'm using but it won't work. I believe something is wrong with `js` codes. How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML code is missing `<html>` and `<body>`, so the jQuery selector won't work.

Comment: @stealthyninja I have <html> and <body> in full code of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you've included jQuery. Then you need to write your script inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code goes here

});
```

or in short

```
$(function(){
    //your code goes here 

});
```

Both functions are called when the DOM is ready. Thus ensuring that event and handlers are bound properly to elements.

[Check this out](http://jsbin.com/wamojiruna/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: As a side note, I'd also change the div tags to "section" tags. HTML5 supports that.

Comment: Yes, Indeed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5 , this is the best site you would get for reading about HTML5 or Javascript.

Comment: @Nielarshi can I make these sections responsive sections?

Comment: Yes, keep width in % and use em for font-size.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. You might not have included jquery library. Use this structure

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>

<body>
<nav>
<a class="nav" id="1" href="#">Section 1</a>
<a class="nav" id="2" href="#">Section 2</a>
<a class="nav" id="3" href="#">Section 3</a>
</nav>

<div class="section" id="1">
Section 1
</div>
<div class="section" id="2">
Section 2
</div>
<div class="section" id="3">
Section 3
</div>


<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```